# Postgres Skipping Duplicate Field in Select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select a limited number of items but only keeping ones with a distinct value for a specific field. I have tried using `SELECT DISTINCT ON(field)` as well as `GROUP BY` but they are both extremely slow because the table is very large. I assume this is because using DISTINCT will actually sort the table into distinct values before selecting at all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(parent) id FROM posts WHERE sub = ? LIMIT 25
```

For my purposes this is unnecessary because I am using a LIMIT and can guarantee the limit will be met without scanning much of the table at all. Similar to selecting a value with a condition, which (without an index) will scan each row and check if it meets the condition before continuing, how can I use not having duplicate fields as a condition?

Another way to think about it is how do I do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (parent) post.id FROM
(SELECT id FROM posts WHERE sub = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT 25) AS post
```

While guaranteeing that there are 25 results. Here the result is very fast but it will usually have less results than required because multiple rows can have the same `parent`.

Comment: Does the `sub` column have an index on it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes

Comment: IMO [good answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177174/88191) for the almost same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're thinking may seem to make sense, but if you think a little deeper, you'll find that it cannot work that way. You want 25 unique result. To give you that, first it needs to go through the records and find the unique ones then return the first 25.

What you actually want is for it to go through the records one by one and check, do I already have similar value? If yes, discard it and continue, if no, add it to the results. Now check, do I already have 25 results? If no, continue, if yes, stop and return the results.

This is not a trivial task to do in a query. Your best bet is to do it in a stored procedure with a cursor. That will be much easier as you are in full control of the flow, just follow the steps as per the description above.

> For my purposes this is unnecessary because I am using a LIMIT and can guarantee the limit will be met without scanning much of the table at all.

If you really know that your first 25 results will be found in the first xx records (say first 100), and that's all you care to achieve, then you can use a somewhat dumb query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (parent) post.id
FROM (SELECT id FROM posts WHERE sub = ? ORDER BY id LIMIT 100) AS post
LIMIT 25
```

Change the 100 to whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't stop to realize what I was trying to do didn't make sense. I will try to write a procedure to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `distinct on`, you should use `order by`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (parent) id
FROM posts
WHERE sub = ?
ORDER BY parent
LIMIT 25;
```

To optimize this query, you want an index on `posts(sub, parent, id)`.

Comment: Well I want to order by postid